# C++ reset locale to "C" globally?

Tags: c++, locale, number-formatting, cout, stringstream

In a project I am currently working on I link to a proprietary dynamic library. As soon as I run the library's initialize function, the behavior of logging and printing of numbers changes.

Commas have been inserted at every third decimal. i.e.

```
cout << 123456789 << endl
```

used to print out `123456789` and now it prints `123,456,789`. This is horribly annoying, because this behavior is not what I want.

This issue is not only apparent in the binary I am compiling, but also shows up in all the `couts` and `stringstreams` in the libraries that I link to it.

I have tried using this line of code after calling the initialize function:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"C");
```

thinking it might reset my locale to the default but to no avail. The commas persist!

This snippet of code:

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale("C"));
```

works to reset the locale of `couts` and every `stringstream` I apply it too. However, do I really need to call `imbue` on EVERY `stringstream` declared in EVERY library I link to? There are some libraries that are proprietary and I cannot actually change their source code.

There must be a way to reset the locale back to `"C"` globally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe `std::locale::global(std::locale("C"));` should do the trick. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global

Note that this only affects streams created *after* this call.

Any streams such as `cout` that the other library already imbued would have to be re-imbued back to the desired default locale.

And finally I would strongly suggest filing a defect report against the library you're using because it's pretty unjustifiable to to unilaterally make such striking global changes within your initialization function.

Comment: yes, but the OP must remember that `locale::global` (as indicated in the linked page) only affect the streams constructed **after** the call. So, `cin`, `cout`, `cerr` and other streams are not imbued with the global locale, one must do that manually;

Comment: @Mark B, Thank you. That worked like a dream. @Massa, thanks for the insight. So I can assume that `streams` inherit the locale of whatever the global locale is at the moment of their declaration?

Comment: they inherit the locale of the global locale is at the moment of their initialization (they can be declared as class members and initialized on constructors, etc. etc.)